# Customizing style of Mahapps.Metro CustomValidationPopup for a single control (not for entire app/window)

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a Mahapps.Metro-based UI where I am trying to customize the Placement of a single TextBox Validation Popup. I just want only this particular TextBox to show its validation errors at the bottom, not application-wide.

Overriding the below mentioned Style in the App.xaml works, but it overrides it for all Validations. Placing this style as a Resource of UserControl or the TextBox doesn't work (which is understandable, since the validation popup doesn't inherits from them).

At the moment I have achieved what I want by rewriting the whole [ControlTemplate](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/Styles/ValidationErrorTemplate.xaml) and altering the Style at the bottom, but I don't like this solution...

```
<Style x:Key="MetroValidationPopup" TargetType="{x:Type controls:CustomValidationPopup}">
        <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Bottom" />
</Style>
```

Is there any way to set above-mentioned Property just for a single TextBox validation?

Alexey Panov - Dresden

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly the same. Did you ever find a solution that didn't involve rewriting the control template?

Comment: Nope :( Unfortunately, I had to stay with my rewritten ControlTemplate and moved on...